# How to generate thumbnail for file with Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to get the thumbnail(preview of the file's contents) for word and pdf files, I am using carrierwave to handle upload.

I config the uploader like this :

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'

class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or ImageScience support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # include CarrierWave::ImageScience

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  version :m do
    process :resize_to_fill => [75, 75]
  end

  version :b do
    process :resize_to_fill => [125, 125]
  end
  ....

end
```

But it can not work with non-image

Comment: What exactly do you mean by thumbnail? Do you mean an icon that indicates the file format or a preview of the file's contents?

Comment: preview of the file's contents, thanks for you reply !

Comment: I'm pretty sure Carrierwave won't do that for you. Images are rendered by the browser, but Word and PDF files are a different matter.